# How to setup file upload from NodeJS/VueJS to another server?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I've created a VueJS App for file uploading in which it will be my admin panel (For CMS) with NodeJS as back-end. Now I want to upload the files that was passed to the NodeJS and move it to another VueJS App which is going to be my primary website in order for me to access the files locally. How can I do it? Any suggestions or different approach will do.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options on how to move the files to another site.

You could store them in a shared bucket or shared directory between your 2 backends or you could add another route to download that file.

You could configure a cronjob to scp or rsync those files to your target machine.

This is really more of a question of how to sync a directory to some place else.

Comment: The setup is for Admin CMS (VueJS) and also the main Website (VueJS) with the NodeJS as the backend. My files that I've uploaded was stored on the NodeJS directory and I want to store it on the Admin CMS (VueJS). So basically its not a question of syncing.